# Flask error handling

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to catch an error generated by flask-sqlalchemy. My code unfortunately can't handle the error because the debugger catches it first. It happens when I try to insert a record into a database with a field that's supposed to be unique but is duplicated.Is there any way around this? This is the traceback.

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError

IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) column username is not unique u'INSERT INTO user (username, password, karma) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' (u'Test', u'test', 0)
Traceback (most recent call last)

    *
      File "/home/josh/Projects/masterpieces_of_code/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 889, in __call__

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

    *
      File "/home/josh/Projects/masterpieces_of_code/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 879, in wsgi_app

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))

    *
      File "/home/josh/Projects/masterpieces_of_code/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 876, in wsgi_app

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] rv = self.dispatch_request()

    *
      File "/home/josh/Projects/masterpieces_of_code/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 695, in dispatch_request

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

    *
      File "/home/josh/Projects/masterpieces_of_code/app.py", line 70, in create_user

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] db.session.commit()

    *
      File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 129, in do

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

    *
      File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 653, in commit

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] self.transaction.commit()

    *
      File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 364, in commit

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] self._prepare_impl()

    *
      File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 348, in _prepare_impl

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] self.session.flush()

    *
      File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1346, in flush

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] self._flush(objects)

    *
      File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1427, in _flush

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] flush_context.execute()

    *
      File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 299, in execute

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] rec.execute(self)

    *
      File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 443, in execute

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] uow

    *
      File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1833, in _save_obj

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] execute(statement, params)

    *
      File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1794, in execute

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] object, *multiparams, **params)

    *
      File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/interfaces.py", line 149, in execute

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] return execute(clauseelement, *multiparams, **params)

    *
      File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1157, in execute

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] params)

    *
      File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1237, in _execute_clauseelement

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] return self.__execute_context(context)

    *
      File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1268, in __execute_context

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] context.parameters[0], context=context)

    *
      File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1806, in _cursor_execute

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] cursor, statement, parameters, context, False)

    *
      File "/home/josh/Projects/masterpieces_of_code/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flaskext/sqlalchemy.py", line 115, in cursor_execute

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] return execute(cursor, statement, parameters, context)

    *
      File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1367, in _cursor_execute

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] context)

    *
      File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1360, in _cursor_execute

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] context)

    *
      File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 288, in do_execute

       [Display the sourcecode for this frame]  [Open an interactive python shell in this frame] cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

    IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) column username is not unique u'INSERT INTO user (username, password, karma) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' (u'Test', u'test', 0)

This is the Copy/Paste friendly version of the traceback. You can also paste this traceback into the public lodgeit pastebin:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/josh/Projects/masterpieces_of_code/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 889, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/josh/Projects/masterpieces_of_code/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 879, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/josh/Projects/masterpieces_of_code/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 876, in wsgi_app
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/josh/Projects/masterpieces_of_code/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 695, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/josh/Projects/masterpieces_of_code/app.py", line 70, in create_user
    db.session.commit()
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 129, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 653, in commit
    self.transaction.commit()
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 364, in commit
    self._prepare_impl()
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 348, in _prepare_impl
    self.session.flush()
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1346, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1427, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 299, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 443, in execute
    uow
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/orm/mapper.py", line 1833, in _save_obj
    execute(statement, params)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1794, in execute
    object, *multiparams, **params)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/interfaces.py", line 149, in execute
    return execute(clauseelement, *multiparams, **params)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1157, in execute
    params)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1237, in _execute_clauseelement
    return self.__execute_context(context)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1268, in __execute_context
    context.parameters[0], context=context)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1806, in _cursor_execute
    cursor, statement, parameters, context, False)
  File "/home/josh/Projects/masterpieces_of_code/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flaskext/sqlalchemy.py", line 115, in cursor_execute
    return execute(cursor, statement, parameters, context)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1367, in _cursor_execute
    context)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1360, in _cursor_execute
    context)
  File "/usr/share/pyshared/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 288, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) column username is not unique u'INSERT INTO user (username, password, karma) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' (u'Test', u'test', 0)

The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.

To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

    * dump() shows all variables in the frame
    * dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object

Brought to you by DON'T PANIC, your friendly Werkzeug powered traceback interpreter.
```

I forgot to mention how flask reacts when I try to handle the error. I get something related to an undefined global. Here's the traceback for that.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/josh/Projects/masterpieces_of_code/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 889, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/josh/Projects/masterpieces_of_code/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 879, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/josh/Projects/masterpieces_of_code/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 876, in wsgi_app
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/josh/Projects/masterpieces_of_code/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 695, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/josh/Projects/masterpieces_of_code/app.py", line 72, in create_user
    except(IntegrityError):
NameError: global name 'IntegrityError' is not defined
```

Comment: I updated my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to put a try/catch in your `create_user` function (masterpieces_of_code/app.py) in the block of code which does the `db.session.commit()`, and handle the exception there.

**Update:** If you are getting a `NameError` for `IntegrityError` then it means you are likely to be missing a

```
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
```

in your `app.py`. That's not a message from Flask, that's Python telling you about an unknown name (because of the missing import) as it interprets the code in `app.py`.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to mention I tried that already. For whatever reason, Flask says that IntegrityError is an undefined global. I've updated my original posting to reflect this.